# есть такой класс Any при проверке на тестирующей системе выдает Failed. Runtime error Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++, классы

```
    struct ICloneable
{
    virtual ICloneable* clone() const = 0;
    virtual ~ICloneable() { }
};



template <typename T>
struct ValueHolder : ICloneable {

    ValueHolder(T value) : data_(value) {};

    ValueHolder * clone() const {
        return new ValueHolder(*this);
    }

    ~ValueHolder() {}

    T data_;
};
class Any
{
public:
    Any() : data_(0) {}

    template < class T >
    Any(T data) : data_(new ValueHolder<T>(data)) {}

    ~Any() 
    {
        delete data_;
        ICloneable * data_ = 0;
    }

    Any(Any const & obj) : data_(obj.data_->clone()) {}

    template <typename T>
    Any& operator=(const T & obj) 
    {
        delete data_;
        data_ = new ValueHolder<T>(obj);
        return *this;
    }

    Any& operator=(const Any & obj) 
    {

        if (this != &obj)
        {
            delete data_;
            data_ = obj.data_->clone();
        }
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename T>
    T* cast()
    {
        if (this) 
        {
            ValueHolder<T> *res = dynamic_cast<ValueHolder<T> *>(data_);
            if (res)
            {
                return &(res->data_);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    ICloneable * data_;
};
```

на локальной машине под ms vs 2017 все компилируется в чем беда помогите?

Comment: А как происходит проверка на тестирующей системе то?

Comment: это на степике содержание тестов неизвестно.

Comment: `if (this)` - бессмысленная проверка. Некоторые современные компиляторы ее просто выкидывают, т.е. рассматривают как заведомо истинную.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался в копировании надо было так

```
 Any(Any const & obj) : data_(obj.data_ ? obj.data_->clone():0) {}
```

Comment: Ну тогда и в операторе присваивания та же ошибка.